# Java: How to check the random letters from a-z, out of 10 letters minimum 2 letter should be a vowels

Tags: java, text, random

I am writing a program to validate the following scenarios:

#### Scenario 1:

I am using the Random class from java.util. The random class will generate 10 letters from a-z and within 10 letter, minimum 2 letters must be a vowels.

#### Scenario 2:

When the player 1  and player 2 form a word from A-Z, he will score some points. There will be a score for each letter. I have already assigned the values for A-Z. At the end of the game, the system should display a scores for player 1 and player 2. How do i do it?

Please help. I will post my code here.

Thanks a lot.

```
===========================================

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FindYourWords {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Random rand = new Random();
  Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  //==================Player object===============================================
  Player playerOne = new Player();
  playerOne.wordScore = 0;
  playerOne.choice = "blah";
  playerOne.turn = true;
  
  Player playerTwo = new Player();
  playerTwo.wordScore = 0;
  playerTwo.choice = "blah";
  playerTwo.turn = false;
  
  //================== Alphabet ==================================================
  String[] newChars = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
    "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
  }; //values of the 26 alphabets to be used
  
  int [] letterScore = {1,3,3,2,1,4,2,4,1,8,5,1,3,1,1,3,10,1,1,1,1,4,4,8,4,10}; // to assign score to the player1 and player 2
  
  String[] vowel = { "a", "e", "i", "o", "u" };  // values for vowels
  int vow=0;
  
  System.out.println("FINDYOURWORDS\n");
  
  int[] arrayRandom = new int[10]; //int array for word limiter
  String[] randomLetter = new String[10]; //storing the letters in newChars into this array
  
  //===============================================================================
boolean cont = true;
  
  while (cont) {
   
   if (playerOne.turn) {
    System.out.print("Letters of Player 1: ");
   }
   else if (!playerOne.turn) {
    System.out.print("Letters of Player 2: ");
   }
   
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayRandom.length; i++) { //running through the array limiter
   int r = rand.nextInt(newChars.length); //assigning random nums to the array of letters
   randomLetter[i] = newChars[r];
   System.out.print(randomLetter[i]+ " ");
   
   }
  
   //input section for player
  
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("Enter your word (or '@' to pass or '!' to quit): ");
   if (playerOne.turn) {
    playerOne.choice = userInput.next();
    System.out.println(playerOne.turn);
    playerOne.turn = false;
   }
   else if (!playerOne.turn){
    playerTwo.choice = userInput.next();
    System.out.println(playerOne.turn);
    playerOne.turn = true;
   }
   //System.out.println(choice);

  
   String[] wordList = FileUtil.readDictFromFile("words.txt"); //Still dunno what this is for
   
   
   if (playerOne.choice.equals("@")) {
    playerOne.turn = false;
   }
   else if (playerTwo.choice.equals("@")) {
    playerOne.turn = true;
   }
   else if (playerOne.choice.equals("!")) {
    cont = false;
   }
   
   
   for (int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
   //System.out.println(wordList[i]);
    if (playerOne.choice.equalsIgnoreCase(wordList[i]) || playerTwo.choice.equalsIgnoreCase(wordList[i])){

  }

   }
  
  
  
  

  }
 }}
```

Comment: Would you please put your code in code tags or indent it? --- Thanks :)

Comment: @Jan - Done that.  I'd also recommend tagging this as homework.

Comment: @duffymo - What makes you think it's homework? I also took utils off since that has no relevancy.

Comment: @Jan - the comment "//Still dunno what this is for" suggested to me that something was given to kalandar that s/he didn't fully understand.  And all the code is crammed into main - a sure sign of someone who's just learning the language (badly) for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

For Scenario 1, IMO the simplest solution would be to generate the 10 chars, count the number of vowels, and if it is less than 2, regenerate the whole set. This would make the result look more "random", in the sense that the vowels can be anywhere within the sequence, and there can be more than 2 of them.

Btw here

```
String[] wordList = FileUtil.readDictFromFile("words.txt"); //Still dunno what this is for
```

the word list is used to check that the word entered by the actual player is a valid word (i.e. it exists in a dictionary).

Once the word is validated, just iterate through its characters, find their index within the alphabet, then sum up their values. For this, you would be better off using a `char[]` instead of `String[]`.

**Update:** code example for generating and validating the characters:

```
final char[] alphabet = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
final Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'));
char[] randomLetters = new char[10];
int vowelCount;

do {
    for (int i = 0; i < randomLetters.length; i++) {
        int r = rand.nextInt(alphabet.length);
        randomLetters[i] = alphabet[r];
    }
    vowelCount = 0;
    for (char actualChar: randomLetters) {
        if (vowels.contains(actualChar))
            vowelCount++;
    }
} while (vowelCount < 2);
for (char actualChar: randomLetters) {
    System.out.print(actualChar + " ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for your comments. For the scenario, could you please where should i count for vowels and regenerate the whole set if it is less than 2 vowels. Sorry this is first assignment at my polytechnic and i am still learning,. hope fully i will be able to do my next assignment on my own. Thanks a millon.

Comment: Hi peter, sorry i am novice to java, still learning, hence i could not understand the following codes.

final Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'));  

and 

for (char actualChar: randomLetters) { 
        if (vowels.contains(actualChar)) 
            vowelCount++; 

May i know what is Set<Character>  and char actualChar. Thanks again

Comment: @kalandar, I recommend reading [Sun's Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/), specifically [Collections](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/collections/index.html) and [The for Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).